# Getting each time Error 429 for APi Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch

I am getting an Error 429, too many requests from api.xyz and I don't know why. I tried with delays but it is on another step and idk where I am wrong. Please let me know if you know what to do

```
const fetchData = async (id) => {
try {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
  };
  
  await delay(9000);
  var response = await fetch(`https://api.xyz/${id}`, options);
  if (response.ok) {

    const data = await response.json();
    return data.moreData ?? null;
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
return null;
};
```

and this is the function where the fetchData is called:

```
const fetchSecond = async (account) => {
const myData = await fetchThings(account);
if (myData .items) {
  const Apples = myData.items.map(async (token) => {
    const surname = await fetchData (token?.id);

    return {
      image: token.meta?.image ?? null,
      name: surname

    };
  };
  return Promise.all(Apples);
}
return [];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because since you're using Promise.all, all those promises start at the same time, and so the requests are sent concurrently (and thus the `delay(9000)` doesn't have the intended effect; what happens is all the requests are sent at approximately the same time 9 seconds later.

Instead, you should use a for loop:

```
  for (const token of myData.items) {
    const surname = await fetchData (token?.id);

    return {
      image: token.meta?.image ?? null,
      name: surname
    };
  });
```